# What date/month does each scene of Cursed Child take place in?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, chronological-order

Can someone make a table of when each scene Harry Potter and the Cursed Child takes place?

When a book or movie takes place in a specific time in the future, I try to keep track of when it takes place so I can read and watch it then. I understand that Cursed Child spans multiple years starting with Albus's first day of school in 2017 or so, and that a lot of the drama is in the 2020-2021 school year. I hope I didn't miss it.

In addition, I know that Cursed Child shows some scenes in the '80s and '90s, and I'd like to have an easy reference for when I want to reread a particular section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1

Act 1

Scene 1-3: (19 years later): Sep 1, 2017

Scene 4: Sep 1, 2017 - September 2017 - Sep 1, 2018 - September 2018 - Sep 1, 2019.

Scene 5: Sometime in 2020

Scene 6: August 2020

Scene 7: Aug 31, 2020

Scene 8: Dream from Jul 31, 1991

Scene 9-15: Sep 1, 2020

Scene 16-19: Sep 2, 2020

Act 2

Scene 1: Dream from sometime between 1984-1990

Scene 2-6: September 3, 2020

Scene 7: Going back in time to November 24, 1994, and then back to the present- September 3, 2020.

Scene 8-19: Sep 4/5, 2020

Scene 20: Going back in time to February 24, 1995, and then back to the present- September 5, 2020.

Part 2

Act 3

Scene 1: Sep 8, 2020

Scene 2-7: September 2020

Scene 8: Going back in time to November 24, 1994

Scene 9: Going back to the present: September 2020. Then back in time to February 24, 1995, Then back to the present September 2020.

Scene 10-11: Sep 2020

Scene 12: Dream of an event that didn't happen from 1984-1990

Scene 13-19: September 2020

Scene 20: Going back in time to June 24, 1995, and then back to October 1981

Scene 21: September 2020

Act 4

Scene 1: September 2020

Scene 2-3: October 30, 1981

Scene 4: September 2020

Scene 5: October 31, 1981

Scene 6: September 2020/October 31, 1981

Scene 7: September 2020, going back in time to October 31, 1981

Scene 8-13: October 31, 1981

Scene 14: October/November 2020

Comment: What are you basing this on?

Comment: @Valorum- It's pretty clear when you read the book. I checked every chapter and got the date or month from them. You can check the script.

Comment: Some quotes or references would help this answer.